# Functional Swift returns error

Tags: swift, functional-programming

Why does r1 work but r2 throw a compilation error (*Cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type '(NSArray, [Int])'*)?

```
func reduce<T1, T2>(input:[T1], initialResult: T2, f:(T2, T1) -> T2) -> T2 {
    var result = initialResult
    for x in input {
        result = f(result, x)
    }
    return result
}

let array2D = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

let r1 = reduce(array2D, []){result, x in
    result + x}

let r2 = reduce(array2D, []){result, x in
    return result + x}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the return type, it silences this error, e.g.:

```
let r3 = reduce(array2D, []){result, x -> [Int] in
    return result + x}
```

---

If you specify that that initial empty array is an `Int` array, the error is silenced:

```
let r4 = reduce(array2D, [Int]()){result, x in
    return result + x}
```

Comment: Thanks, I never thought to use [Int].  I guess the compiler sometimes needs a bit of help in inferring the array type.  Odd that it could infer correctly in r1 but not r2 though.

Comment: Agreed. I rely on type inference a lot, and stumbled across similar issues when doing some functional programming with complicated `map` function in extension of generic. It got confused and specifying the return type cleaned it up.